# php update multiple select option values in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ia_pages` (
  `pages_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `search_type` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `search_block_position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`alphabet_search_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;



INSERT INTO `ia_pages` (`pages_id`, `page_name`, `search_type`, `search_block_position`) VALUES
(1, 'home_page', 'product_search', 'right_column'),
(2, 'product_page', 'category_search', 'right_column'),
(3, 'category_page', 'product_search', 'right_column');
```

and the html form like this

```
<table id="admin-settings">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Page Name</th>
      <th>Search Type</th>
      <th>Show Search in Block</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Home Page</td>
     <td>
      <select id="search_type" name="search_type">
        <option value="product_search">Product Search</option>
        <option value="category_search">Category Search</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="show_block" name="show_block">
        <option value="left_column">Left Column</option>
        <option value="right_column">Right Column</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product page</td>
    <td>
      <select id="search_type" name="search_type">
        <option value="product_search">Product Search</option>
        <option value="category_search">Category Search</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="show_block" name="show_block">
        <option value="left_column">Left Column</option>
        <option value="right_column">Right Column</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category page</td>
    <td>
      <select id="search_type" name="search_type">
        <option value="product_search">Product Search</option>
        <option value="category_search">Category Search</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="show_block" name="show_block">
        <option value="left_column">Left Column</option>
        <option value="right_column">Right Column</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>            
   <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="4">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="button">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when I make any changes when selecting any values in the form and click then it is making all the rows values same.
My update query is like this

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$username = 'root';
$dbname = 'ia_pages';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$username);
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname) or die ("no database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    $search_type = $_POST['search_type'];
    $show_block = $_POST['show_block'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $update_query = "UPDATE `pages` SET `search_type` = '$search_type',`search_block_position` =  '$show_block'";
        $query_execute = mysqli_query($con, $update_query);
        if($query_execute) {
          echo "Data has been updated";
        } else {
          echo "data has not been updated";
          }
    }
```

Here it is changing all the values even only option has been changed. So all the values in the database has been converted to same. So how to fix this? I want to update the values in the database which has been changed in frontend.

Comment: You have two dropdown with name "show_block" and "search_type".

Comment: is there any good method to do this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `where` clause to your update statement. Without it all rows are updated.

Comment: That I don't know. You wanted to know how to fix the update query, adding the `where` clause will do that. You need to wrap the entire thing in a `<form>` and use a hidden field for the `id` or use a `<button>` and bind the `id` to the buttons value.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
<td>Home Page</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
 Home Page
 <input type="hidden" name="page_name" value="Home Page" />
</td>
```

Apply similar changes to other page name types.

And in your `update` query add a `where` clause like this:

```
$update_query = "UPDATE `pages` SET "
                . "`search_type` = '$search_type', "
                . "`search_block_position` =  '$show_block' "
                . "where `page_name` = '$page_name';
```

***Update***:

If all the select lists are in the same form element, then in `php` script, as the input elements have same names, you need to read the values into arrays.

```
$page_names = $_POST[ 'page_name' ];  
$search_types = $_POST[ '$search_type' ];  
$show_blocks = $_POST[ '$show_block' ];
```

Then your update statement shall be like:

```
update ia_pages
  set search_type =
        case page_name
             when '$page_names[ 0 ]' then '$search_types[ 0 ]' -- Home Page
             when '$page_names[ 1 ]' then '$search_types[ 1 ]' -- Product Page
             when '$page_names[ 2 ]' then '$search_types[ 2 ]' -- Category Page
             else search_type
        end
    , show_block_position =
        case page_name
             when '$page_names[ 0 ]' then '$show_blocks[ 0 ]' -- Home Page
             when '$page_names[ 0 ]' then '$show_blocks[ 1 ]' -- Product Page
             when '$page_names[ 0 ]' then '$show_blocks[ 2 ]' -- Category Page
             else show_block_position
        end
```

This query will update all the related fields.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But anytime when I am doing any update it is only taking the last values of options. 1st and 2nd td options are not doing any update. It is always taking last option pair which are present in the last td

Comment: The `select` element names are the same in the top group as they are in the bottom group.

Comment: @Tony: Yes. OP needs to read them as an array to use in sql statement.